# Stock Management Workflow

Tags: expresso-store

I just purchased Store a few weeks ago and my clients added another request is that she want to be able to track the change in her stock, not just the remain stock number after order/sale but also the newly imported ones.

For example she has a product call T-Shirt, original stock level is 10.
At the end of the month, she sold 9, has 1 remaining in stock.

Now she wants to add 9 more from a certain supplier to make sure the stock level at the beginning of next month is 10 again. How would you suggest her to do so and how we can track the number of T-shirt we have import from a certain supplier during a certain period of time?

Please let me know if I didn't explain clearly enough.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store has simple stock tracking facilities, but it shouldn't be used as a replacement for a proper accounting system. It is designed to let you limit the number of sales to however many you have in stock, and if you get more stock in you can update this number to allow customers to purchase the item again.

However, tracking incoming stock from suppliers, or generating reports of how many items need to be ordered is really beyond what Store was designed to do. You should probably look at writing your own module / queries to generate this data, or look at off the shelf accounting software which has a full inventory management system.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I didn't get any notification from StackExchange so I wasn't aware of this.